# Jmeter Active Threats Over Time

Tags: performance, graph, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am confused. I have the following in my test:

1. Threat Group 1 - 5 vUsers
2. Threat Group 2 - 5 vUsers
3. Threat Group 3 - 5 vUsers
4. .........
5. Threat Group 11 - 5 vUsers

All of them have think time between each request and are not the same. Each threat group has its own requests. The ramp-up period for each is 1 second. So each one will add 1 user per second and the total execution time is 20 mins. All the threat groups run simultaneously.

When i run the test i get the following graph from JMeter:

[image]

What i want to achieve is this:

[image]

I am running the test from GUI mode and i can see that during the test there are always 55 active users but this is not shown at the graph. I tried another graph generator to aggregate the results but it is worst. What i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you're missing there because we don't know how you configured your Thread Groups.

> The ramp-up period for each is 1 second. So each one will add 1 user per second

this is not true, it means that it will add start all users in the Thread Group in 1 second. See [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details if needed.

If you want to add 1 user per second you need to make ramp up time equal to the number of users in thread group, in your case it's 5.

Also given 5 seconds ramp-up and 20 minutes test duration you won't be able to see the chart you produced as it assumes that 25% of test duration users are ramping up and the same time they're ramping down so I think you should go for something like 5 minutes (300 seconds) of ramp-up

For you it might be easier to consider going for i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can easily create arbitrary load patterns:

[image]

you can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of **Custom Thread Groups** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. maybe i said it wrong. My ramp-time is 5 so 1 second each user. I have tried also your suggestion but still the same. I have also tried 5 minutes but still the same. Each threat group it  takes roughly 5 minutes to finish so i added an iteration of the each scenario because i thought interacting will keep the users active. It actually keeps all 55 users active but it is not shown in my graph